# sqlite subquery for group of ranked items

Tags: sql, sqlite

The table has three columns (Group, Rank, Score), with composite primary key (Group,Rank).  Each Group has at least one entry with Rank of 1 and a score.  If more than one row per Group, it will have a rank greater than one and a score.  For example:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| Group | Rank | Score |
+-------+------+-------+
|     1 |    1 |   100 |
|     1 |    2 |    99 |
|     1 |    3 |    80 |
|     2 |    1 |    70 |
|     2 |    2 |    68 |
|     2 |    3 |    50 |
|     2 |    4 |    20 |
|     3 |    1 |    80 |
+-------+------+-------+
```

My goal is to pick all rows "close" to each Group's top score, where top score is defined to be score of Rank value of 1 per Group.  In the above example, Group 1 has top score of 100, Group 2 has top score of 70, Group 3 has top score of 80.  We want to choose all rows that are at most 5% smaller than the top scores.  For the above example, the resulting selection would return:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| Group | Rank | Score |
+-------+------+-------+
|     1 |    1 |   100 |
|     1 |    2 |    99 |
|     2 |    1 |    70 |
|     2 |    2 |    68 |
|     3 |    1 |    80 |
+-------+------+-------+
```

My second goal is to place the ratio of score/top_score as a new column, which would obviate the above goal.
Thanks in advance.  For SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, off of the top of my head.

```
SELECT s."Group"
  , s."Rank"
  , s."Score"
  , s."Score"/ts."Score" as "ScoreRatio"
FROM scores s
  JOIN (
      SELECT "Group", "Score"
      FROM scores
      WHERE "Rank" = 1
  ) ts
  ON s."Group" = ts."Group"
    AND 0.95 * ts."Score" <= s."Score"
```

Comment: tested and it works well. thanks!  But the division requires casting since the values can be integer.